# Adding a custom input type for QGIS Model Builder

Tags: qgis

I've been learning about how to add custom algorithms in the QGIS Model Builder which thanks for the extensive python API meets most of my needs.

But there are times I can see the need for inputs to a model that aren't available like a filtered list of current layers or query a REST API for valid selectable values. I spent about an hour looking from different angles for developer documentation that tells me how to do this but I've failed to find anything. Are inputs hard-coded into QGIS?